# Should I use simple random sampling instead of stratified sampling when some strata have low counts?

Tags: sampling, stratification, observational-study, survey-sampling

I am designing a survey for which I would like to stratify "events" by state / province, creating $h=86$ strata for the particular dataset I'm working with. However, there are some strata with low counts.

Using proportional allocation with a budgeted sample size of $n=400$ events out of $N=9046$, some strata are not selected because they occur so infrequently in the sampling frame i.e. $n/N \centerdot N_{h} < 1$ so the inclusion probability for units in some strata is 0. In this case, to ensure that all businesses have some probability of inclusion, should I instead use simple random sampling?

Comment: Have you tried any resampling? Do you have less than 2 records per class?

Comment: Bearing in mind I have updated the numbers in my question, I have as many as 11 records in some strata. Could you clarify what you mean by "resampling" in this context?

Comment: Synthetic generation of samples that are under-represented. Removing samples that are too close to each other. Most popular lib for that is [imbalanced-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). It follow `sklearn` interface, so it's really comfy.

Comment: Edit to my comment above: as many as 11 records for strata with low counts. I have not heard of using resampling methods in survey design. Do you have any literature that you can point me to that discusses resampling in the context of survey design?

Comment: Mashreghi, Haziza and Léger (2016) - A survey of bootstrap methods in finite population sampling